# Java add padding before a string BJP4 Exercise 3.17: padString

Tags: java, string, for-loop, methods, padding

```java
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(padString("hi", 8));
    }

    public static String padString(String string, int length) {
        int wordLength = string.length();

        for (int space = 1; space <= length - wordLength; space++) {
             string = "." + string;
        }
        return string;
    }
}
```

This code works the way it is suppose to, but how? The output is ......hi (Correct)
why does it not print .hi.hi.hi.hi.hi.hi (Wrong but why)
I'm confused, why does the string not print out 6 times as well? The period prints 6 times but not "hi". Please can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Because `string = "." + string;` inserts a single `.` at the beginning of `string` (it does not repeat `string`). In fact, your code could be improved with a `StringBuilder` (which might also make this clearer for you). Like,

```
public static String padString(String string, int length) {
    int count = length - string.length();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string);
    for (int space = 0; space < count; space++) {
        sb.insert(0, '.');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Sorry i still dont get it. If I add another string to it say String x = "go"; and i add it to string = "." + string + x; it prints out ......higogogogogogo. Why do "go" get printed 6 times?

Comment: The code in this answer is equivalent to (and more efficient than) your original post. Note that `string` is only added to the output once. Your code was `string = "." + string;` **not** `string += "." + string;` (which still wouldn't quite match your expectations, but would be a lot closer there to). Also, the code in your comment includes no loop so it doesn't make any sense. But I would guess because you added `x` on every iteration of your hypothetical loop. Print the value on each iteration (or use a debugger).

Answer (score 0):

1) The first time when the loop is executed `string` variable gets the value of .hi

2) After the first time, the loop "concatenates" the dot to .hi until the last iteration.

The purpose of "+" operator is concatenation and not to re-insert the "hi"

Hence, the output. Other thing you could do is to set a breakpoint in the code and Debug as Java Application to see what happens each iteration.